# Initialize and declare dynamically multiple variables of random entities in a loop in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, random, macros

This is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#define ENTITY(A) entity##A
#define ALM(A) alm##A

struct TEntity{
private:
    int sumx;
    int sumy;
    const char * rep;
    int m_ix;
    int m_iy;
public:
    TEntity(int x, int y, int sum_x, int sum_y, const char * txt);
};

TEntity::TEntity(int x, int y, int sum_x, int sum_y, const char * txt) {
    m_ix = x;
    m_iy = y;
    sumx = sum_x;
    sumy = sum_y;
    rep = txt;
}

class IAlmacenable {
private:
    void * element;
public:
    IAlmacenable(void * e);
    IAlmacenable();
    void * getValue();
};

IAlmacenable::IAlmacenable(void *e) {
    element = e;
}

IAlmacenable::IAlmacenable() {
    element = nullptr;
}

void * IAlmacenable::getValue() {
    return element;
}

class TList {
private:
     std::vector<IAlmacenable*> elementos;
     int position;
public:
    TList();

    int Size();

    int Push(IAlmacenable* psz);
};

TList::TList() {
    elementos = std::vector<IAlmacenable*>();
    position = 0;
}

int TList::Size() {
    return elementos.size();
}

int TList::Push(IAlmacenable* psz) {
    int res = 0;
    if (elementos.size() >= elementos.max_size()) {
        res = -1;
    }
    else {
        elementos.push_back(psz);
    }
    return res;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    TList *list = new TList();
    //we can put entities in the list and the rest will be filled up to 5
    int size = list->Size();
    for(int i = size; i<5;i++){
        const char c[] = {(rand() % 2 ? 65 + rand() % 25 : 97 + rand() % 25), '\0'};
        TEntity ENTITY(i)(rand() % 10, rand() % 10, rand() % 5, rand() % 5, c);
        IAlmacenable ALM(i)(&ENTITY(i));
        list->Push(&ALM(i));
        size++;
    }
    //do things like printing their value...
    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

I need to create a new variable everytime it run the "TEntity ENTITY(i)" line, 
the problem is that it creates the same variable always, I think it is because it creates the variable entityi and therefore it is overwriting on the same variable, besides it seems that the random it generates is always the same number since all entities have the same values ​​in all its parameters. The c variable create a const char * random variable between a-z, A-Z , I don't put the print code because it is unnecessary, so what can I do? Is there any way to dynamically create variables of entities whose values ​​are random?

**EDIT** 
Here is the new code fixed (the macros have been eliminated since they were not necessary and the necessary code has been included to be able to execute it) but there is still the same problem that they are generated with the same parameters (since they are still the same variable):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

struct TEntity{
private:
    int sumx;
    int sumy;
    const char * rep;
    int m_ix;
    int m_iy;
public:
    TEntity(int x, int y, int sum_x, int sum_y, const char * txt);
    void movimiento();
    void pinta();
};

TEntity::TEntity(int x, int y, int sum_x, int sum_y, const char * txt) {
    m_ix = x;
    m_iy = y;
    sumx = sum_x;
    sumy = sum_y;
    rep = txt;
}

void TEntity::movimiento() {
    m_ix += sumx;
    m_iy += sumy;
}

void TEntity::pinta() {
    gotoxy(static_cast<short int>(m_ix), static_cast<short int>(m_iy));
    printf("%s", rep);
}

void gotoxy(short int x, short int y)
{ 
    COORD pos = {x, y};
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(output, pos);
}

void clear()
{
    system("cls");
}

class IAlmacenable {
private:
    void * element;
public:
    IAlmacenable(void * e);
    IAlmacenable();
    void * getValue();
};

IAlmacenable::IAlmacenable(void *e) {
    element = e;
}

IAlmacenable::IAlmacenable() {
    element = nullptr;
}

void * IAlmacenable::getValue() {
    return element;
}

class TList {
private:
     std::vector<IAlmacenable*> elementos;
     int position;
public:
    TList();

    int Size();

    int Push(IAlmacenable* psz);

    IAlmacenable* First();

    IAlmacenable* Next();
};

TList::TList() {
    elementos = std::vector<IAlmacenable*>();
    position = 0;
}

int TList::Size() {
    return elementos.size();
}

int TList::Push(IAlmacenable* psz) {
    int res = 0;
    if (elementos.size() >= elementos.max_size()) {
        res = -1;
    }
    else {
        elementos.push_back(psz);
    }
    return res;
}

IAlmacenable* TList::First() {
    IAlmacenable* res;
    if (elementos.empty()) {
        res = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        res = elementos.front();
        position = 1;
    }
    return res;
}

IAlmacenable* TList::Next() {
    IAlmacenable* res;
    if (elementos.empty()) {
        res = nullptr;
    }
    else {
        int pos = position;
        int size = elementos.size();
        if (pos < size) {
            res = elementos.at(position);
            position++;
        }
        else {
            res = this->First();
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    TList *list = new TList();
    //we can put entities in the list and the rest will be filled up to 5
    int size = list->Size();
    for(int i = size; i<5;i++){
        const char c[] = {(rand() % 2 ? 65 + rand() % 25 : 97 + rand() % 25), '\0'};
        TEntity *entity = new TEntity(rand() % 10, rand() % 10, rand() % 5, rand() % 5, c);
        IAlmacenable *alm = new IAlmacenable(entity);
        list->Push(alm);
        size++;
    }
    while(true){
        clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            reinterpret_cast<TEntity *>(list->Next()->getValue())->pinta();
            reinterpret_cast<TEntity *>(list->Next()->getValue())->movimiento();
        }
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: macros are expanded long before runtime

Comment: You could almost say they happen before compile time (if you feel the preprocessor is not actually part of the compiler)

Comment: The problem is that it creates the same variable always, I think it is because it creates the variable entityi and therefore it is overwriting on the same variable, besides it seems that the random it generates is always the same number since all entities have the same values ​​in all its parameters

Comment: You have bigger problems anyway. The scope of the object is the loop iteration, so (a) it can & should have the same name in each iteration, and (b) you're storing pointers to things that die.

Comment: Yes, the entity will be called `entityi`, but I'm not getting why that's a problem. Of what relevance to anything is the object's name? Almost certainly your real problem is the confusion regarding object lifetime.

Comment: why do you think those variables need some generated names, when anyhow you push them in a list?

Comment: So, what can I do to create differents variables with random parameters and put them in a wrapper (void *) to create a list?

Comment: @user463035818 Because I need different named variables to get their pointers, but their are in the for scope, so what can I do?

Comment: @YamikaIzumi _"I need different named variables to get their pointers"_ This is simply not the case. You seem to have confused names with lifetime. You did the lifetime wrong, and you're trying to change the names to fix the lifetime but just made the names wrong too instead. The names have nothing to do with the pointers, at all, whatsoever.

Comment: So what can I do? Maybe do "TEntity *entity = new TEntity(...)" and put them into a list?

Comment: @YamikaIzumi Yes maybe that - I did suggest that in my answer.

Comment: But if I try that, how can I put it in a wrapper (IAlmacenable)? I need a pointer to put in void *

Comment: " the problem is that it creates the same variable always" no it does not, it is a new variable each time, even if they reuse the same memory address.

Comment: @Slava I editted the text to add an executable code, I tried to create a new TEntity with new (also the IAlmacenable) and it doesn't work, it doesn't create any entity in the console

Answer (score 3):

There is some confusion here.

Some points:

1. The macro is not fit-for-purpose, as you already know; you're just creating a variable name `entityi` each time;
2. That doesn't matter! The object only exists for the duration of the loop iteration anyway; C++ doesn't let you create multiple objects with the same name at the same time. In fact you can get rid of the entire macro stuff and just call the object `entity`;
3. Now that that's out of the way, you're getting repeated results because you're storing a pointer to each iteration of that local variable — on each occasion, that's a dangling pointer to an object that's been destroyed. Don't store dangling pointers!

You can either:

- Dynamically allocate the objects that you're adding to the list, or
- Store actual objects rather than pointers-to-objects.

Either way, the local-scope name is irrelevant and certainly need not change repeatedly for each loop iteration.

Comment: But I need their pointers because I will put them in a wrapper (IAlmacenable)

Comment: @YamikaIzumi Then you'll need to dynamically allocate them so that you can finely control their lifetime. Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: I am learning it at university and I do not know what you mean by assigning dynamically? I must go creating it in the for and enter it in an auxiliary list so that it can be consulted and entered in my TList?

Comment: @YamikaIzumi Noooo. When you use `new` you are "dynamically allocating". I ask again which C++ book you are using? It should explain all of these basics.

Comment: The C++ programming language. Bejarne Stroustrup. 
I have edited my question eliminating the macros and adding the necessary code for its execution, in addition I have tried to make new in the creation line of the TEntity but when I do not create anything

Comment: @YamikaIzumi The code still uses the macros, and still stores pointers to local variables that go out of scope. There's no `new` in there. Did you accidentally copy/paste the old code instead?

Comment: I have already updated the code with the new so that you can see that when executing it does not create any entity, the previous code was simply to show how it created exactly the same units with the executable code

Comment: @YamikaIzumi Okay you've edited it again now and it looks much better. There are still issues, but at least the problems in that loop are now fixed.

Comment: The problem now is the const char[] because it will not change so it will be the same value, I am thinking how to do that

Comment: @YamikaIzumi No, that is not true. Again, it is a _different_ `const char[]` on each loop iteration. It is not the same object each time. Did you examine its value before making this claim?

Comment: Yes and all are different and all the entities have different text but when they enter in the while(true) loop all have the same text (the last letter that was creatted, but all the parameters of the entity are fine, I don't know why only the text is the same and the last created)

Comment: When the c is created, entity only get its pointer so the last value of c is the only one that remains because the pointer is the same all the time in the debugger, is there any way to maintain it? Or should I create a list that stores every "const char *"?

Comment: @YamikaIzumi Then you must be storing `c` inside `TEntity` as a pointer, rather than actually taking ownership of the data. Why are you doing that? In fact, what's `c` for? Why do you need it? Just remove it...